# Can an android library have its own unique application ID?

Tags: android

I am creating an android library that uses a third party library under the hood and this third party tool requires an application ID. My issue is that users who use my library will have different Application ID which I may not account for. So is it possible to give an android library and application ID as a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to give an android library and application ID as a unique identifier?

No, sorry. If you try to have `applicationId` in your library's `build.gradle` file, you will get a build error.

> My issue is that users who use my library will have different Application ID which I may not account for

Have the users of your library give you their application ID via some method, function, constructor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Android library is not an application hence It doesn't have any application ID. Instead it has a package id (Single).